# Функция tokenize работает неправильно

Tags: python, token, nlp

Код:

```
from razdel import tokenize

[_.text for _ in tokenize("стяжкa нейлоновая под винт")]
```

Вывод

```
['стяжк', 'a', 'нейлоновая', 'под', 'винт']
```

Возможно ли исправить эту проблему?

Да, я могу добавить это слово в исключения, но если таких слов будет много, что можно придумать?

Этот метод токенизации мне нравится, так как он может отделять токены так:

```
[_.text for _ in tokenize("привет100")]
```

Вывод:

```
['привет', '100']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хотел ещё вчера дать ответ, но вопрос был удалён. Как понять, что с вашим текстом что-то не так - проверить коды символов. Видно, что в первом слове последняя буква английская, а не русская:

```py
for x in "стяжкa нейлоновая под винт":
    print(f'{ord(x):>4}', x, '!!!' if ord(' ') < ord(x) < ord('А') else '')
```

Вывод:

```
1089 с 
1090 т 
1103 я 
1078 ж 
1082 к 
  97 a !!!
  32   
1085 н 
1077 е 
1081 й 
1083 л 
1086 о 
1085 н 
1086 о 
1074 в 
1072 а 
1103 я 
  32   
1087 п 
1086 о 
1076 д 
  32   
1074 в 
1080 и 
1085 н 
1090 т
```

Answer (score 2):

Буква а набрана в английской раскладке на клавиатуре, замените на а в русской раскладке и все заработает нормально.